# How do I create a MySQL statement to split array data to new table format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have old table which the data stored as

```
tbl_id  tbl_data
--------------------
1       1,2,3,4,5,6
2       3,4,5
```

Now I want convert these to many-to-many relationship table.

```
user_id user_option
-------------------
1       1  
1       2
1       3
...
```

Basically I insert the data in php

```
$old = explode(",", $data['tbl_data']);
$query = $db->query("SELECT tbl_id, tbl_data FROM old_table"); 
  while($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO new_table SET .....");
  }
```

May I know, there have a way to get this done with single MySQL statement?

Comment: +1 For the initiative to properly normalize this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are best off to do it in PHP code.  Though MySQL does have a way to locate values via `FIND_IN_SET()`, it doesn't have an equivalent method to `explode()` to easily separate them.  It would be possible to write a lot of ugly looping and string manipulation in a MySQL procedure, but it's *much easier* to do in PHP code.

There are some suggestions for handling string splitting in the comments beneath the [MySQL string function docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) but they don't really address looping inserts to normalize out a column.  It really is easier to just handle in a scripting lanugage like PHP.

But it is good that you are sorting this out and properly normalizing the column.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Looks like `FIND_IN_SET()` fit to my need at the moment.